# Weird css path anomaly in component, if css file not in the same directory

Tags: css, angular, components

If I put the css file into the same directory as my component is, everything works, but when I edit the path to another directory I get this error in browser console:

```
Uncaught Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings."
```

Works:

```
styleUrls: [
   'admin.css'
],
```

Doesn't work:

```
styleUrls: [
   '../../css/admin.css'
],
```

Works with **scss** file which is in the same directory:

```
styleUrls: [
   '../../css/admin.scss'
],
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you replicate the problem on StackBlitz?

Comment: Check the path as you have entered in styleUrls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. I had project default styles set to scss. To fix do following:

Open **angular.json** file

Change .scss

```
"schematics": {
           "@schematics/angular:component": {
                   "styleext": "scss"       
             }  
  }
```

to .css

```
"schematics": {
           "@schematics/angular:component": {
                   "styleext": "css"        
             }  
  }
```

and restart with ng serve